# Docker container health monitoring

Tags: docker, kubernetes, resources, consumption

What are the tools available to monitor docker container resource consumption? Recently, application containerization is becoming more popular ever since Docker came. But, it's important to collect resource consumption of containers to benchmark different applications.

Answer (score 4):

My recommedation is cAdvisor that already used by kubernetes node monitoring and OpenShift metrics engines. And Prometheus is also popular, the information is taken easily from searching google.

**cAdvisor**

[ https://github.com/google/cadvisor ]

**Example links**

- Monitoring Docker Containers – docker stats, cAdvisor, Universal Control Plane

  [ https://blog.codeship.com/monitoring-docker-containers/ ]
- Running cAdvisor

  [ https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/running.md#other-configurations ]
- Docker, cAdvisor, InfluxDB and Grafana

  [ http://softwaretester.info/docker-cadvisor-influxdb-and-grafana/ ]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see  the resources consumption of your containers you can execute the command `docker stats` on your terminal it returns CPU, memory, network usage by container

Answer (score 0):

NexClipper is the simple and easy container monitoring tool which to collects statistics, status, process, network, environment, volume, and log.

https://github.com/TheNexCloud/NexClipper

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.